# State_pressed change color of a view

Tags: android

I have this `selector` xml file which is applied to a `RelativeLayout` as a background element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#449def" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#2f6699" />
            <corners
                android:radius="3dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

     <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#f3ae1b"
                android:endColor="#bb6008"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#bb6008" />
            <corners
                android:radius="10dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

My question is: Why doesnt the color of this layout change when the state is changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to make the layout clickable.
add:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

to your RelativeLayout definition

Comment: This works nice! But when I have a child element inside the layout, this won't trigger. Do you know how to accomplish this aswell?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of behavior you want to achieve, you could try adding `android:addStatesFromChildren="true"`to the RelativeLayout.